# How to get reaction from wait_for("reaction_add")

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am developing a little reaction roles bot in discord.py - for this I am trying to use the .wait_for() function with the "reaction_add" parameter. The problem is that I need to get the emoji from the reaction, which is not working as an error is shown:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Seemingly there is something wrong with the way I am trying to get the emoji, but I couldn't find the proper way to get the emoji.

```
interaction = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
if interaction.emoji == "": 
    await interaction.user.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 emoji = ""

 message = await ctx.send("Test")
 await message.add_reaction(emoji)
 reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add")
 if user != bot.user:
       if reaction.emoji == emoji:
              await user.add_roles(user, role)
```

or

```
emoji = ""

def check(reaction, user):
     return user == ctx.message.author and reaction.emoji == emoji

message = await ctx.send("Test")
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
await bot.add_roles(user, role)
```

Comment: Both `bot.add_roles` and `client.add_roles` is outdated.

Comment: give us the good practice then :)

Comment: It’s not good practice, it simply will not work…